# Arquivos de javascript não carregam em produção. Como resolver?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Estou com o seguinte problema. Em produção alguns arquivos JS não aparecerem, já em desenvolvimento aparecem.

Produção:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desenvolvimento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Mas quais arquivos que não aparecem?

Comment: @BrunoCasali, editei a pergunta. De uma olhada.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que você não está por dentro de como o Rails lida com *assets* (Javascript, CSS e imagens). Não deixe de ler esta sessão do guia oficial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

parece que você renomeou o `application.js` para `main.js`, correto?

se você olhar o arquivo `main-#{checksum}.js`, ele deve conter todos os arquivos que você está dizendo que "não carregam".

Answer (score 0):

**Updatee**

Um carinha teve um provlema parecido com o seu aqui... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079585/rails-application-not-loading-all-javascript-files-production)

Para resolver ele adicionou todos os arquivos que deveriam ser carregados em produção no Application.js, você poderia postar o seu ?

Tenta isso também:
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Verifica também se todos os seus assets estão na pasta `public`...

e se caso não der certo o [plano b aqui!!!](http://www.42.mach7x.com/2012/05/25/javascript-file-not-compiled-in-production-with-rails-asset-pipeline/)

Valeuu, espero ter ajudado!!